# Debugging Redisson Subscribe Timeouts

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redisson

I am using Redisson 3.8.2 to connect to a replicated AWS elasticache, after a while of operation my client frequently gets timeout exceptions trying to subscribe to topics.

I've checked the load on AWS and the load on my client, AWS is barely above idle and the client has far fewer subscriptions than it should be able to support (subscriber pool * subscriptions per connection).

I have tried adjusting the subscription connection pool and subscribers per connections settings but still get the issue.

The exception is thrown at a high level, timing out waiting for the Redisson promise to sync, looking through the detail code behind the promise there is a lot happening involving at least 2 locks in the java code and async futures to subscribe and attach the listener.

Is there a way I can get more debugging information from Redisson about where is it timing out / what stage it is getting to and when it fails seeing what the state of the connection pools and the connection entries are?

```
org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Subscribe timeout: (7500ms)
at org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.syncSubscription(CommandAsyncService.java:142) ~[redisson-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
at org.redisson.RedissonTopic.addListener(RedissonTopic.java:133) ~[redisson-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
at org.redisson.RedissonTopic.addListener(RedissonTopic.java:109) ~[redisson-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
```